# iphone like voicemail listbox in android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a iphone like voicemail listview in android. is it possible to have similar listvew.?

In Android we have to have all view inflated in getview of customadapter class. but in phone play button is visible only when users selects the listview item.

Is this possible in android if yes any ideas/pointers.

Comment: Make a custom ListView Adapter and initially make the button visibility `INVISIBLE` and make it `VISIBLE` when the user clicks on the list item.

Comment: setting visibility inside onsetitemclicklistner? If yes then how will getview will know the button status which was already infalted?

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: I believe the approach will take a customadapter. Suppose if we use make invisible in onsetitemclicklistner() then is there a way to inform getview() in adapter to save status of the button?.